# Can't establish ssh connection: Permission denied (publickey,password). althought I have the correct password and able to login in mobaexterm

Tags: ssh, windows

I am working on a remote Ubuntu server, from my windows local computer.

I can login to the remote host with mobaxterm, so the password is correct.
But the ssh fails.

```
 ssh -v  naomi1@52.232.64.127
OpenSSH_for_Windows_7.7p1, LibreSSL 2.6.5
debug1: Connecting to 52.232.64.127 [52.232.64.127] port 22.
debug1: Connection established.
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file C:\\Users\\Naomi Fridman/.ssh/id_rsa type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file C:\\Users\\Naomi Fridman/.ssh/id_rsa-cert type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file C:\\Users\\Naomi Fridman/.ssh/id_dsa type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file C:\\Users\\Naomi Fridman/.ssh/id_dsa-cert type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file C:\\Users\\Naomi Fridman/.ssh/id_ecdsa type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file C:\\Users\\Naomi Fridman/.ssh/id_ecdsa-cert type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file C:\\Users\\Naomi Fridman/.ssh/id_ed25519 type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file C:\\Users\\Naomi Fridman/.ssh/id_ed25519-cert type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file C:\\Users\\Naomi Fridman/.ssh/id_xmss type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file C:\\Users\\Naomi Fridman/.ssh/id_xmss-cert type -1
debug1: Local version string SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_for_Windows_7.7
debug1: Remote protocol version 2.0, remote software version OpenSSH_7.6p1 Ubuntu-4ubuntu0.3
debug1: match: OpenSSH_7.6p1 Ubuntu-4ubuntu0.3 pat OpenSSH* compat 0x04000000
debug1: Authenticating to 52.232.64.127:22 as 'naomi1'
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT sent
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT received
debug1: kex: algorithm: curve25519-sha256
debug1: kex: host key algorithm: ecdsa-sha2-nistp256
debug1: kex: server->client cipher: chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com MAC: <implicit> compression: none
debug1: kex: client->server cipher: chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com MAC: <implicit> compression: none
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_KEX_ECDH_REPLY
debug1: Server host key: ecdsa-sha2-nistp256 SHA256:Ig1UiMRoK7Kw9HEoS1baYd2PpSeh+GlQtaeFKPKiBBI
debug1: Host '52.232.64.127' is known and matches the ECDSA host key.
debug1: Found key in C:\\Users\\Naomi Fridman/.ssh/known_hosts:1
debug1: rekey after 134217728 blocks
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS sent
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS received
debug1: rekey after 134217728 blocks
debug1: pubkey_prepare: ssh_get_authentication_socket: No such file or directory
debug1: SSH2_MSG_EXT_INFO received
debug1: kex_input_ext_info: server-sig-algs=<ssh-ed25519,ssh-rsa,rsa-sha2-256,rsa-sha2-512,ssh-dss,ecdsa-sha2-nistp256,ecdsa-sha2-nistp384,ecdsa-sha2-nistp521>
debug1: SSH2_MSG_SERVICE_ACCEPT received
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey,password
debug1: Next authentication method: publickey
debug1: Trying private key: C:\\Users\\Naomi Fridman/.ssh/id_rsa
debug1: Trying private key: C:\\Users\\Naomi Fridman/.ssh/id_dsa
debug1: Trying private key: C:\\Users\\Naomi Fridman/.ssh/id_ecdsa
debug1: Trying private key: C:\\Users\\Naomi Fridman/.ssh/id_ed25519
debug1: Trying private key: C:\\Users\\Naomi Fridman/.ssh/id_xmss
debug1: Next authentication method: password
debug1: read_passphrase: can't open /dev/tty: No such file or directory
naomi1@52.232.64.127's password:
```

I enter the correct password, but it fails:

```
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey,password
debug1: No more authentication methods to try.
usr@host: Permission denied (publickey,password).
```

I tried to remove  ~/.ssh/known_hosts, and I tried to copy it to the server, but it didn't help.

Comment: are using `ssh` from a powershell or cmd window? and do you have an `authorized_keys` file on the ubuntu server with your key in?

Answer (score 0):

Try ssh with -t option.

```
ssh -t user@server.example.com
```

Also , you can share your client .pub public file to your server ( in yourhomedirectory/.ssh/authorized_keys )  and try with public key method without password.